# Adding Voice Dictation (microphone) to ToolBar

Tags: ios, voice-recognition

What i am trying to do is:

1. Add one button (Microphone image) in toolbar.
2. On click of that button, the iOS default voice dictation should get call.
3. [image]
4. Query: I assume that we can not call default voice dictation but want to confirm.
   Is their any workaround or any approach to call voice dictation on click of button in toolbar?
5. (The query is that dictation button (Mic) get display in keyboard
   (for textfield & textview)& on click of that button(Mic) dictation
   functionality comes to play, can we add similar button (like Mic) to
   toolbar (for textfield & textview) & on click of button dictation
   functionality should comes to play.)

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dictation is only possible in a text field, and can thus only be started from the keyboard (afaik). It is also not supported for all languages, so it depends on what keyboard is active.

Those buttons are usually seen in chat apps, where they record an audio clip without translating it to text.

Comment: Yes the keyboard get appears only for textfield & textview with toolbar. your statement (Dictation is only possible in a text field, and can thus only be started from the keyboard (afaik).) is not clear to me.

Comment: The dictation function turns speech into text. Text can only be placed in a text field. Without a text field, there is nowhere to dictate into. Because of that, Apple put the dictation button on the keyboard, since a keyboard is already linked to a text field.

Comment: Yes this part is well know & the query is that dictation button (Mic) get display in keyboard  (for textfield & textview)& on click of that button(Mic) dictation functionality comes to play, can we add similar button (like Mic) to toolbar  (for textfield & textview) & on click of button dictation functionality should comes to play.

Comment: Yes This is the answer i was looking for. Great Thanks. If you like suggesting any workaround please let me know. Thanks